# Php последовательное добавление записей в разные таблицы mysqli

Tags: php, база-данных, циклы, mysqli

Задача, при отправке формы, сохранить все данные.
Пример формы:

```js
$(".blank_size").each(function () {
  var $wrapper = $(".blank_sizes", this);
  $(".add", $(this)).click(function (e) {
    $(".blank_sizes_list:first-child", $wrapper)
      .clone(true)
      .appendTo($wrapper)
      .find("input")
      .val("")
      .focus();
  });
  $(".blank_sizes_list .remove-field", $wrapper).click(function () {
    if ($(".blank_sizes_list", $wrapper).length > 1)
      $(this).parent(".blank_sizes_list").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="client" placeholder="Заказчик" > <br><br>

<div class="blank_size">
      <div class="blank_sizes">
        <div class="blank_sizes_list">
        <div class="blank_size_info"><input type='text' onkeyup='fun(this)'  name="product[]" value="" autocomplete="off" size="15" required/ placeholder="Товар"></div>
     </div></div>
      <button type="button" class="add">Добавить товар</button>
     </div>
<input name ="submit" type="submit" value="Сохранить"></p>
```

```
//Получаем POST
//Записываем: 
$result1 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO zakaz (client)   VALUES ('$client')");
//Получаю последний ID
$lastIDzakaz = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
//Получаю массив
$myArray = $_POST; 
$count = count($myArray['product']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$blankProduct = $myArray['product'][$i] ;
}
$id_zakaz = $lastIDzakaz;
//Записываем данные во вторую таблицу
$resultAdd = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO product (id_zakaz,product) VALUES ('$id_zakaz','$product')");
```

Правильно ли брать последний id и из полученного id производить сохранение во вторую таблицу? А если будет несколько записей одновременно?
За совет по оптимизации кода буду благодарен.